# On validate revise html code using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I use this code for validation:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script>
      function validateNew() {
        var x1 = document.forms["register"]["firstname"].value;
          if (x1 == null || x1 == "") {
           alert("Please enter your first name.");
      return false;
     }

   }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="register" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateNew()">
 <label id="fname_lbl" class="">First Name
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But I want to do something a little different. I had this code a while back, but I cant remember where I put it. Basically, instead of a pop up window, I want the validate to conditionally trigger code in the html, which will accomplish the goal of preventing the submission, but show, let's say, text above the field that says, in red, "Required Field".

The pseudo-code:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script>
      function validateNew() {
        var x1 = document.forms["register"]["firstname"].value;
          if (x1 == null || x1 == "") {
      $trigger = for label id('fname_lbl') class=="require";
      return false;
     }

   }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="register" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateNew()">
 <label id="fname_lbl" class="<? $trigger ?>">First Name
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Where the class named "require" will turn the font color of 'First Name' to red.

So on the validation, when the code finds out there is no first name, it then, using a trigger variable, modifies that variable, which is read inside the quotes of 'class'.

I know my pseudo-code is way off. I just remember being able to do something like that a couple years ago.

---

EDIT

I found that code snip

```
<head>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#b_down").change(function() {

            if ($(this).val() < 20 ) {
                $("#pmi").show();
            }else{
                $("#pmi").hide();
            } 
        });
    });
 </script>
 </head>
<body>    
<select name="b_down" id="b_down">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
<option value="3" >3</option>
</select>

<? if ($row['b_down']<2) { ?>
<span id="pmi" style="display;" class="dropt">PMI:&nbsp; 
<? } else { ?>
<span id="pmi" style="display:none;" class="dropt">PMI:&nbsp; 
<? } ?>
```

Basically, on the change event, it either shows or hides a particular input. Not sure how to apply it to my project.

Comment: You are on the right track. Just create a boolean for each field you validate and update your UI based on that field's validity. Also keep a "global" boolean that you update in line with each field boolean. Then return the value of that global boolean.

Comment: There are a bunch of libraries out there for validation that do this sort of thing. If you're looking to roll-your-own code, you might want to check out the source code from (for example) [jQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) or any of those other libraries you can find via a google search

Comment: As an aside, make sure you're doing some sort of server side validation.  Client side validation via javascript can be bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>LIGHTBOX EXAMPLE</title>
        <style>
                .normal {
                color: #0f0;
                }
                .required {
                color: #f00;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="register" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateNew();">
            <label id="fname_lbl" class="normal">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
    function validateNew() {
        var x1 = document.forms["register"]["firstname"].value;
        if (x1 == null || x1 == "") {

            document.getElementById("fname_lbl").className = "required";
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
```